# Why is "Improve Edit" on suggested edit considered a Reject and not an Accept?

Tags: support, bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

If the reviewer chose to "Improve Edit" my suggestion, why is my suggestion "Rejected"?

See https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2563541

It says:

> **Rejected** Jul 23 '13 at 2:23:
>   Michael Petrotta reviewed this Jul 23 '13 at 2:23: **Edit**
>   Community♦ reviewed this Jul 23 '13 at 2:23: **Reject**
>   nathanchere reviewed this Jul 23 '13 at 2:23: **Approve**
>   Esti reviewed this Jul 23 '13 at 2:22: **Approve**

In fact you can see Michael Petrotta's edit here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17799597/revisions and it basically contains what I did (code formatting, grammar correction). Only thing Michael did was to revise the tags to only have [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). **So by this loophole, basically Michael took full credit for my work *(not that he intended to, but what it appears to be)*, and I'm penalized as having suggested an edit worthy of a Reject.**

I have queried https://data.stackexchange.com and ascertained that Michael Petrotta has selected **"Improve Edit"** *(or its equivalent back then)*, as the status Id is for "Edit" and not for "Reject and Edit".

So the basic meaning of choosing to "Improve Edit" is *"I approve of your edits, but I can improve upon them."* as opposed to "Reject and Edit" which means *"I reject your edits, but I will edit the original on my own."*

Following that meaning, I should have **3 Approve** votes (one of which comes from Edit) and **1 Reject** vote. Since the majority is clearly an Approve of my edit, why then is the overall decision "Rejected"?

Is this a flaw in the suggested edit review system? Or am I just missing something here?

Comment: Well, 1. It was in 2013, why ask now? 2. he obviously unchecked that your edit was useful, which is understandable: You only replaced one bad tag with another bad one. Always strive to do worthwhile edits, like he did.

Comment: @Deduplicator I checked the database of SE and it has the status 5 (which is for Edit), as opposed to status 19 (which is for Reject and Edit). In today's reviews, status 5 is used for cases where reviewer chose to "Improve Edit".

Comment: @ADTC And that system was put in place after 2013.  That status code didn't even exist back then.

Answer (score 6):

Before [an overhaul of the suggested edits review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/213575), there was only Approve, Reject and Edit. Edit had a checkmark specifying if "mark this edit as helpful" which was enabled by default. The user in question unchecked the mark, which caused that community rejected the edit. I'm not sure if these details are included in the data dump, but I think they can be inferred otherwise.

Comment: Possible to get a data dump?

Comment: @ADTC is the same as SEDE or data.stackexchange.com

Comment: If the reviewer unchecked the checkmark, how can we tell from the database at data.se? Is there a log of this action?

Comment: @ADTC "I'm not sure if these details are included in the data dump, but I think they can be inferred otherwise."

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, you should familiarize yourself with why Community will step in and review a post.  You can read more in [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits) but the short version is

> - A reviewer either improves an edit, or rejects and replaces it with a different edit
> - A user with full edit privileges saves an edit over yours

Your case is the first.  When one of these situations occurs, an instant accept/reject action is required, so Community has been given special mod-like powers to handle the instant accept/reject cases.  Anytime a review needs to be handled by the reviewers only without a typical 3 accept/reject votes, Community steps in and provides the "moderator" action.

That is the case now and has always been the case, but as [Braiam points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323986/250725), the specific implementation (in terms of the options available to the reviewer) is slightly different now than it was 3 years ago, although the general idea is the same.

To expand on the difference between what happened and what you expected to happen, and the history behind the changes Braiam mentioned, in the past there was a concept of a "minor edit".  In fact there was an entire edit reject reason just for that called "Too Minor".  If a reviewer felt an edit didn't do enough, they were welcome to reject the edit on those grounds.  However, what constituted a "minor edit" was left to the determination of the individual reviewers.  Some had a much higher threshold for minor than others.

And at that time, there was no "Reject and Edit" and "Improve Edit" buttons like you see now, there was just "Edit".  When a reviewer decided that they wanted to edit the post while reviewing, they could click "Edit" and then would be able to edit the post, using the suggested edit as a starting point.  There was actually no way to revert to the previous revision within the edit window itself without manually undoing the suggested edit.

And when the reviewer was done with the edit, they had the option of unchecking a box that said "the suggested edit was helpful" (it was checked by default).  This essentially was the predecessor to both "Improve Edit" and "Reject and Edit".

- If the box was left checked, the edit was instantly approved, the suggested edit was applied, and then the improved edit was immediately applied as the current revision.  The suggested editor's edit was part of the revision history of the post.
- If the box was unchecked, the edit was instantly rejected, and only the improved edit was applied to the post.  The suggested editor's edit was not included in the revision history of the post at all.

---

For the specific edit, we can only guess why the reviewer chose to handle it as he did.  Most likely the reviewer decided that your edit was incomplete (i.e the "too minor" case I mentioned above), and felt that your effort was not sufficient to approve the edit and provide you with the +2 rep.  It doesn't matter if the diff today isn't reflecting what you actually changed.  In the end the reviewer himself felt it wasn't sufficient to warrant leaving that "suggested edit was helpful" box checked.  The only person that could really address why would be the reviewer and I doubt he could tell you given it happened 3 years ago.

---

Comment: For your comment, it's not true as I did improve upon the other problems in the post. But somehow **the review diff is not showing this** though it shows the final content (that's another problem). In fact, that's something that I always do when I see a badly formatted post, even in 2013. *Unless I missed out on this particular post. - Will need to further check the history...* In any case, shouldn't "Edit" status mean Approve and not Reject? There's a separate "Reject and Edit" status; what's that for, then?

Comment: @ADTC I tried to address your comment as best as I could in my edit.  Since you said the diff was inaccurate, I removed the references to what actually changed and tried to address the core issue you raised